# "Battle of..." and "seige of..." capitalization

Tags: capitalization

I edit a lot of military history articles, and I know that named battles use a capital "B" for "Battle", e.g. the Battle of Agincourt. However, when it's a siege rather than a pitched battle, most sources out there seem to favour a lower-case "s", e.g. the siege of Orleans. Could anyone shed any light on why this might be?

Comment: I would guess that it's because "Battle of ..." is literally inaccurate and so must be a title, and so gets a capitalized name. The Battle of Agincourt was a battle *at* Agincourt, whereas the siege of Orleans actually was a siege of Orleans.

Comment: @remarkl Interesting theory, and it makes sense. I suppose we could add that very few pitched battles take place actually _in_ their namesake towns, so the literal description would be "the battle _near_ Agincourt".